# Saving date to Mongoose from Angular 6 form returns data one day earlier

Tags: node.js, angular, mongoose

I'm using Angular 6 to save some form data, specifically a date. The form is submitting the date as (date: "2018-07-02T00:00:00.000Z") and that's what get's saved into mongoose. Then when I retrieve all events to display on the page, the date that gets interpolated shows as one day earlier... for example 07/01/2018

Here's my GET call

```
ngOnInit() {
this._eventService
  .getEvents()
  .subscribe(
    (response) => (this.events = response),
    (error) => console.log(error)
  );
```

}

and my interpolated call on the page

{{ event.date | date: 'longDate' }}

Seems like the data is getting saved from form as correct date, then in mLab I'm able to verify correct day and only once it's displayed it's a day earlier

Comment: Just looked at unformatted date returned and it's the correct date. Why would the Date pipe operator pull back the date by a day.

Answer (score 0):

When the date is displayed it uses Time Zone info of the client. You are saving the date as UTC to the database but when you want to display it, it converts the date into the time zone of the current client.
Open your browsers Console and type

```
 new Date("2018-07-02T00:00:00.000Z")
```

You will see a different time if your timezone is not UTC

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually reviewing an article about this now. (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8319). Curious though as I'm saving the information using my computer and retrieving it using my computer. Shouldn't they be the same? And... this will be an issue for the site. What should I be doing to correct this? I'm a bit lost. Thanks so much

Comment: You should send the timezone information to the server somehow. You can send timestamp to the server instead of Date string
`new Date("2018-07-02T00:00:00.000Z").getTime()`